# The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a source table with  three fields

```
Declare @tmptvp table
(
ID int,
StartDate Datetime,
EndDate Datetime
)


Insert @tmptvp values(1,'2013-04-28','2013-04-30')
Insert @tmptvp values(2,'2013-05-01','2013-06-30')

select * from @tmptvp
```

My target table is 'InsertDate' contains the following data.

```
Insert InsertDate values(1,'2013-04-28','2013-06-30')

while merging
MERGE (@tmptvp)  as TGT
USING 
(select ID,StartDate,EndDate FROM  @tmptvp)  AS SRC
ON
(TGT.StartDate = SRC.StartDate OR TGT.EndDate = SRC.EndDate)  

WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET TGT.StartDate = CASE WHEN SRC.StartDate < TGT.StartDate  THEN SRC.StartDate ELSE TGT.StartDate END,
TGT.EndDate   = CASE WHEN SRC.EndDate > TGT.EndDate THEN  SRC.EndDate ELSE TGT.EndDate  END, 


 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT (ID,StartDate,EndDate)  
 VALUES
(SRC.ID,SRC.StartDate,SRC.EndDate);
```

Above merge statement throws
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once.
 This happens when a target row matches more than one source row.
 A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times.
 Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row,
 or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Answer (score 0):

please check this site

http://www.sqlsafety.com/?p=665

The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.” several times and am always forced to run back through the query logic to see what has occurred.  Reading the message it is fairly self explanatory as to what has happened.  A row in the target table will be affected more than once from within the MERGE statement which causes the query to fail.

Best regards